# firmware-iwlwifi not working on linux kernel 4.6 - debian jessie

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, iwlwifi

I just installed Debian Jessie yesterday, was having issues with my multi-monitor setup and so upgraded the 3.x kernel to `linux-generic-4.6`. Now, for whatever reason, my `iwlwifi` driver has stopped working. Luckily I have a USB network card so I am not internet-less, but I can't seem to get the built in card working which is pretty frustrating.

This is the output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:3f:db:8a:88:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and `lspci -nn | grep Wireless`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 48)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled `iwlwifi` multiple times from the normal debian repo's as well as from backports.

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the latest driver from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-7265-ucode-16.242414.0
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Reboot

Unload and load driver:

```
rmmod iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Or you can use backports:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar xvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and reload the driver.

Comment: Ahh thank you! May hypno-toad bless you!

Comment: Thank you very much!